# XPage iFrame to another database (XPiNC)

Tags: iframe, lotus-notes, xpages

I've got 2 Notesdatabase both run completly on Xpages, my Adress and Correspondence.
One holds all the adresses and the other all the correspondence for these adresses.

Now i wanted to put an iframe into my adress xpage to access the correspondence from there,
this all works well in a browser but once i switch to Notes the iframe won't load.

```
<iframe 
src="#{javascript:getParaValueByKey('CorrespondenceDB')+'/xpCorrespondenceView.xsp?rows='+compositeData.rows+'&amp;key='+compositeData.key}" 
style="border: none; width: 99%; height: 400px;" ></iframe>
```

I noticed that the current notes URL looks something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:50136/xsp/DEV!!adresse.nsf/xpAdresse.xsp?documentId=589CBCAEAADE52F2C12579D40020BF4B&action=editDocument
```

so i tried to switch it to:

```
<iframe 
    src="#{javascript:@Word(context.getUrl().toString(),'!!', 1)+getParaValueByKey('CorrespondenceDB')+'/xpCorrespondenceView.xsp?rows='+compositeData.rows+'&amp;glAdrID='+compositeData.key}}" 
    style="border: none; width: 99%; height: 400px;" >
</iframe>
```

A computedText shows for the src above:

```
http://127.0.0.1:50136/xsp/DEV!!correspondence.nsf/xpCorrespondenceView.xsp?rows=5&key=833C5C1633E34E6CC1256CD20041DBE5
```

Path and everything looks ok but it still won't open the iframe, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you accessing this on your local replica when using XPiNC and on the server in the browser?

Comment: The URLs are from accessing the Xpage on the server (DEV) in XPiNC.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put in a view control that points to the other database, filtered by category name or column value? Use Xpages native controls instead of forcing HTML "square pegs" to fit into "round holes"?

Comment: Because with a view control i can't open the the correspondence document, when i mark a column as link. The generated Link will look like this and sadly wont work.`http://DEV/adresse.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?databaseName=DEV!!Correspondence.nsf&documentId=13009BE2046C30F4C1257A2F00367637&action=editDocument`

Comment: Is DEV listed in your hosts file? Try adding it in and see if it the link works. I've not done this myself, so am just speculating....

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an iFrame. When working in XPiNC you should use a composite application for this. Your address database publishes the key that the correspondence consumes.

Of course David's suggestion to use a view (or repeat or Rest) control and point it to the other database works as well.

Comment: Using a view control and pointing it to another database will work for the viewing and even for searching documents. But marking a column as 'show as link' to get the document to open will result in an error, when you click on it.

Comment: Then try the component approach